# MAGIT: How to quickly see diff (changes) between current buffer/file and last commit of that same buffer/file?

Tags: diff, commit, magit

I have checked for similar questions but I couldn't find an updated one on MAGIT especifically.

My goal is to quickly visualize the diffs between the current file I am working on (just the file, not the whole folder/files in git) and the last commit of the same file, just to see the recent additions/deletions. What is the quickest way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: `C-c M-g` will pop up a menu just for that fie and you can hit `d` there to get a diff

Comment: Thanks, but it's confusing. From where shall I press those keys? From magit-status buffer? Does the cursor must be on top of the commit?

Comment: Just from the buffer where you're editing that file

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way just to see deletions (not both deletions and insertions?)

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry - might be Google to the rescue there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-c M-g` will pop up a menu just for that fie and you can hit d there to get a diff. Thanks @Dave F